# Latex chapter refrencing giving the last chapter last section reference

Tags: latex

I have a problem referencing a chapter. I used a label bellow each title however, it is not giving the right reference. I tried some fixes but it did not work (nameref, varioref, cleveref)

my latex code is as follows

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french,arabic,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{utf8}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{breakcites}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%\usepackage{asect}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{acro}

\input{annexes/abreviations}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    citecolor=violet
}


% ref packages
\usepackage{nameref}
% folowing  must be in this order
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\input{chapters/chap1.tex}
\input{chapters/chap2.tex}
\input{chapters/chap3.tex}
\input{chapters/chap4.tex}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibliography}



\end{document}
```

in chapter 1

```
\chapter{title1}
\label{chap1}

here is defined the label{chap1}
\section{section1}
this is section1 
\section{section1}
this is section1 

\section{section1}
this is section1
```

in chapter 3

```
\chapter{title3}
\label{chap3}
text reference Chapter \ref{chap1}
```

However, the reference shows the last section of chapter 1

[image: chapter latex reference]

I am using texmaker quick build to compile the code. Here is the complete example on overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/read/rxkmhxcbcgqc
we can also notice that referencing the first chapter does not work.

Comment: the complete example can be found in the link above

Comment: Please read about the [mcve]. Your main file uses many packages that are probably not necessary. I'm not going to work on your problem if I have to first install a bunch of packages. The MCVE should also be here in the question; links can break, and that overleaf website only comes up blank for me. This is probably due to my paranoid browser settings, but I'm not willing to change them for your question. Long story short: make it easy for us to help you, [edit] your question to include all relevant things (and nothing more) here.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal non-working example would be

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\chapter{title}\label{key}

test \ref{key}

\end{document}
```

You can work around this problem using the approach from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238442/36296

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}

\makeatletter

\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\xstring\select@language{\main@Arabi@language}}%
\if@rl\SAV@@part[\textRL{#1}]{\textRL{#2}}%
\else\SAV@@part[\textLR{#1}]{\textLR{#2}}%
\fi} 

\def\@spart#1{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\xstring\select@language{\main@Arabi@language}}%
\if@rl\SAV@spart{\textRL{#1}}%
\else\SAV@spart{\textLR{#1}}%
\fi}  

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\xstring\select@language{\main@Arabi@language}}%
\if@rl\SAV@@chapter[\textRL{#1}]{\textRL{#2}}%
\else\SAV@@chapter[\textLR{#1}]{\textLR{#2}}%
\fi} 

\def\@schapter#1{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\xstring\select@language{\main@Arabi@language}}%
\if@rl\SAV@schapter{\textRL{#1}}%
\else\SAV@schapter{\textLR{#1}}%
\fi}  
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{title}\label{key}

test \ref{key}

\end{document}
```